# *X is not available in A and(?) so(?) neither/nor(?) is it available on B*

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-requests, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

Let the semantics of A and B be such that something that is not available in A is consequently not available in B (e.g. because B is contained in A).

What is the proper way to assert that *X is not available in A ,(?) and(?) so(?) neither/nor(?) is it available on B* ?

I have seen related questions with neither/nor, but here I would like to express *consequence* as well as *consecutive negation*.

Comment: I don't think this is a question about English.

Comment: @HotLicks have you actually read it?

Comment: The word order and construction you’re going for here can’t accommodate all the things you want to include, I’m afraid. _So/thus/consequently_ cannot coexist with _neither/nor_ in a full clause like this. You’ll have to either break up _neither_ into _not… either_ (“and so it is not available in B either”) or reduce the clause by removing the verb (“and thus nor in B” or “and nor, thus, in B”). _Also not_ is another option, which I personally think is more likely to be how a native speaker would phrase if naturally.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, that is a great answer! It really clarifies it for me at least. I suppose my native language bias made me think this would have to be possible, but your alternatives serve perfectly. Why not make this an "answer post" so I can choose it as the solution?

Comment: The unavailability of X in A consequently excludes it from B.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a form of "consequence", since that's what you want to say.

> X is not available in A; consequently it is not available on B, either.

It sounds better to me with "either" at the end, but it works without it, too.

Answer (score 1):

***of course*** (or ***obviously***) ***it can't***

> X is not available in A; so of course it can't be available in B.

"*of course*" is mostly used nowadays to merely emphasize that something is obvious, and you get some of that here too, but we also get the benefit of the original meaning: what follows is a result of following the *course* of reasoning from what came before. "*So*" links the first idea to the obviousness of the second.

Finally, "*can't be*" is a little stronger than "*is not*". We use a modal auxiliary to rule out possibility rather than stating a mere fact. Again, this emphasizes that X's unavailability in B is a result of its unavailability in A.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be "nor" or "neither". "Neither" is more formal.

If you want to use "but", the sentence should be revised as *"...but it is available on B."*